# Mos amplifier region of operation

Tags: mosfet, amplifier

[image]

In the solution presented I have doubt regarding the 3rd region where both Mos are in saturation.When M2 shifts from triode to saturation how can we say that that the Vout will still be increasing?Isn't it only possible if the (Vgs1-Vth1)>(Vgs2-Vth2)?.Otherwise the current in the 2nd MOs will be dominant and Vout will decrease.Please explain.[Note: Vin varies from 0 to Vdd=3V.Nothing is said about Vb].

Comment: What is your X axis?

Comment: X axis is Vin..

Comment: Then where is Vb plotted or defined?  Why do i ask ? Because Vout only depends Vg1/Vgs2

Comment: Nothing has been mentioned about Vb in the question.

Comment: This is a exercise problem from Razavi Cmos Integrated Circuits.No specific voltage for Vb is given anywhere.

Comment: Then Vout is undefined. Read again. If e.g. Vb=0 then Vout=Vdd

Comment: I also could not understand why Razavi Sir hasn't mentioned any particular value for Vb.

Answer (score 0):

Let's momentarily assume that the output voltage remains constant. Increasing \$V_{in}\$ will also cause \$v_{GS1}\$ to increase. And *this* increase in \$v_{GS}\$ will cause M1 to conduct *more* current - provided it still has a \$V_{DS} > 0\$.

This ultimately shifts the balance of the "fight over the output voltage" in favor of M1. More current will go from VDD to OUT compared to the current sunk by M2 from OUT to GND. The net result is that the output voltage goes **up** until \$v_{GS1}\$ is small enough again to match the current sunk by M2.

Answer (score 0):

Since  both Nch FETs are  Voltage controlled conductors above Vth (using some  standard threshold for Vgs =Vt like 1mA = Ids)...

The graph indicates Vout=0 at Vin=Vth1 or Vt1 or “Vgs=Vt”

M1 is source follower to output thus non-inverting like an emitter follower output.

There is no load applied to  Vout so both M1,M2 share the same current and since Vb is undefined, we can assume M2 is fixed Vgs bias just above Vt to maximize the dynamic gm range of M1 vs Vgs1=Vin. Considering tolerances of bulk production FETs for Vt, we can assume it is just high enough to make R2 (equivalent) a fixed resistance like Vt = 2V @1mA or R2 =2kohm.

Now consider the circuit just like a quadratic V-controlled emitter follower output. Vout now rises as you say “(Vgs1-Vth1)>(Vgs2-Vth2)” plus some tolerance V to account for differences in production.

- These Vt’s are very tightly matched on the same chip, yet in bulk production like hFE in BJT’s can be >+/-50%

  It is important to realize early on, that production variances for Vt tolerance is wide and this affects the saturation threshold resistance Rsat (never specified) AND also the triode RdsOn conductance tolerance which is well specified in datasheet.

I assume you understand an emitter follower characteristic.

Does this help?